# Using Python to remove punctuation from a currency value in a list

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have the following list which I would like to convert into a Pandas DataFrame, split into columns. I use comma (`,`) to split it into columns. So, I would like to remove comma (`,`) from the amount values ONLY e.g. `$1,2344.10`. Is there a way to remove them using Python? Or even RegEx would do.

`[1, , , 123, , 01/01/2000, S, $1,234.12 , $0.00 , $0.00 , $0.00 , $0.00 , $0.00 , $0.00 , $0.00 , $1,234.12 , $0.00 , $0.00]`

I'm using beautifulsoup to extract the list mentioned above

```
table_details = soup.find('div', class_='k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable')
rows = table_details.find_all('tr')
for td in rows:
    row_td = td.find_all('td')
# Remove all HTML tags
str_cells = str(row_td)
text = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text()
print(text)
```

This code basically gets all the text between  . Is there something that could be done to strip down the comma while extracting?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Is this list in a file, and do you have any control over it? Typically, with comma-separated values like this, elements that contain commas themselves should be enclosed in quotes: `"$1,234.12"` so that there's no need for any more complicated parsing.

Comment: Could you provide the code that returns this list?

Comment: You can get the help in your problem, however, please put your code whatever you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: @wwii I have done some research on how to get rid of the comma from a particular string. I have added more details to the question and included the code I have used.

Comment: @Seb I'm extracting this data from a website and converting it to a pandas dataframe for further data analysis. I don't have much control over the list unless it's extracted and saved as a list. The problem I'm facing is when I'm trying to split this list into columns after converting it to dataframe. The delimiter is comma (,) for splitting it into columns, so the cell with $1,2345 get split into two columns. I can't use space either because some cells have space at the end and some have empty cells, which would again get split into multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

This may work if your list is a string

```
list = str(list)
for i in range(1,len(list)-1):
    if list[i+1].isdigit() and list[i-1].isdigit() and list[i]==',':
        list.pop(i)
```

But the best way to avoid working with exceptions is to read the list the proper way, with proper separators, and replace all the commas